# How to Mock JobBuilder.ScheduleBuilder.schedule() using powerMockito?

Tags: junit, mockito, jobs, job-scheduling, powermockito

I have a set of code to add a job to a particular queue inside my @Activate method of my Job class. When I run JUnit for the class, I'm getting nullPointer exception. PFB my code:

```
// MyJob.java

public abstract class myJob implements JobExecutor{

private ScheduledJobInfo jobInfo;
@Reference
private JobManager jobManager;

private String topicName = "abc/xyz";
private String cron= "0 0 0/12 ? * MON-FRI *";

// my activate method
@Activate
protected void activate(final Map<String, Object> config) {
jobInfo = jobManager.createJob(topicName)
                .properties(config)
                .schedule()
                .cron(cron).add();}
}

@Override
public JobExecutionResult process(Job samplejob, JobExecutionContext samplecontext){
// logic inside process method
return samplecontext.result().message("test message").succeeded();
}
```

//my JUnit test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class myJUnitTest{

@Mock
private Job job1;
@Mock
private JobExecutionContext context1;

@InjectMocks
private myJob sampleObj = new MyJob();

@Test
public void sampleActivate() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put("abc", "abc");

    sampleObj.activate(config);
    sampleObj.process(job1, context1);
}
```

My results:
1. While the JUnit covers "jobManager.createJob(topicName).properties(config)", nullPointer is thrown when the flow comes to ".schedule()"
2. I'm not able to cover "return samplecontext.result().message("test message").succeeded()", there also nullPointer is thrown.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code is calling several methods in a chain of calls:

```
jobManager.createJob(topicName)
                .properties(config)
                .schedule()
                .cron(cron).add();
```

So you need to consider what each method is returning.  First, the createJob method is invoked for the jobManager object.  So if you have mocked jobManager, you can use Mockito `when` to set up an expectation for what should be returned when that method is invoked on the object.  That method should return a JobBuilder object, so you need to set that expectations.  Then, on the JobBuilder that is returned by createJob, you can set the expectation for what should be returned by the properties method.  The properties method returns a JobBuilder, so again you can use `when` to set that expectation.

Once that is set you can then mock out the schedule() method that will be invoked.  I am guessing this isn't all of your code or I think you would have encountered an exception when trying to use jobManager, since it isn't shown as mocked anywhere in your code.

You probably need to add something like the following:

```
@Mock
private JobManager jobManager;

JobBuilder jobBuilder = Mockito.mock(JobBuilder.class);

Mockito.when(jobManager.createJob("abc/xyz").thenReturn(jobBuilder);
```

..and then more of the same to continue the mocking for each method that will be invoked.  Each method invoked may need to be mocked so that when invoked it will return the expected object (which may be another mock).